# cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:500: error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != __null in function Mat

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I have 2 cameras (1 - Kayeton KYT-U200-R01 and 2 - similar one but for IR) running on my Raspberry Pi 3. Everything worked fine but suddenly after resolution has been changed from 640x480 to 1024x768 on both the second camera refused to work. The error I get switching over to the second camera is as follows:

> cv2.error:
> /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:500:
> error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != __null in function Mat

Even after restoring previous resolution and system reboot the second camera won't work. If someone came across this issue before, please write your solution, thanks in advance.

Here is my Python code:

***Camera initialization***

```
def init_cameras(self):
    self.cap_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    self.cap_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)

    # set resolution
    self.cap_1.set(3, 640)
    self.cap_1.set(4, 480)

    self.cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.cap_2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)

    # set resolution
    self.cap_2.set(3, 640)
    self.cap_2.set(4, 480)
```

***Frame reading***

```
def get_img_frame_from_camera_two(self):
    ret, img_frame = self.cap_2.read()
    # to save it when 'capture' button will be clicked
    self.save_last_img(img_frame)

    qFormat = QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888
        
    img_frame = QtGui.QImage(img_frame, img_frame.shape[1], img_frame.shape[0], img_frame.strides[0], qFormat)
    img_frame = img_frame.rgbSwapped()

    return img_frame
```

***Run method of a separate thread reading a frame***

```
def run(self):
    while(True):
        while(self.event_running.isSet()):
            img_frame = self.camera_manager.get_img_frame_from_camera_two()
            frame = {}
            frame['img'] = img_frame
                if self.camera_manager.queue_frames_camera_two.qsize() < 10:
                    # put frame to queue
                    self.camera_manager.queue_frames_camera_two.put(frame)
                    # notify listener on new frame added in
                    self.camera_manager.signal_camera_two.emit()
                else:                        
                    print(self.camera_manager.queue_frames_camera_two.qsize())
```

Comment: What about the stack trace, which tells us what statement the error originates from? That's pretty relevant information.

Comment: File "/home/pi/windows/project/Utility_managers/Py_camera_manager.py", line 105, in get_img_frame_from_camera_two
    ret, img_frame = self.cap_2.read()